# Windows Batch Script using FOR

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I need to create an ftp script to from a file list. To create the script to from this list, I need to use the FOR command, but I do not know to use.

List of files is called "verifica.txt" and within it have the lines:

```
C:\xml\UPLOAD\35150650956911000165550550000198041000464010.doc
C:\xml\UPLOAD\35150650956911000165550550000198051000463983.doc
C:\xml\UPLOAD\35150650956911000165550550000198061000463999.doc
C:\xml\UPLOAD\35150650956911000165550550000198071000464003.doc
C:\xml\UPLOAD\35150650956911000165550550000198081000464027.doc
```

I am not able to make my script leave the right way. In this code I'm trying to generate my FTP script to put

```
echo in10xml> upload_files_xml.ftp
echo xml_in10 >> upload_files_xml.ftp
for / f% i in (verifica.txt) echo put% i / content / UPLOAD /% i >> upload_files_xml.ftp
echo bye >> upload_files_xml.ftp
```

When you run the command FOR above him to give me the result below:

```
user
password
put C:\xml\UPLOAD\35150650956911000165550550000198041000464010.doc /content/UPLOAD/C:\xml\UPLOAD\35150650956911000165550550000198041000464010.doc
bye
```

The need FOR generate the result as follows:

```
user
password
put C:\xml\UPLOAD\35150650956911000165550550000198041000464010.doc /content/UPLOAD/35150650956911000165550550000198041000464010.doc
bye
```

Comment: Your for statement is wrong. Type `for /?` at a command prompt and see how the `/f` argument works. And unless you've transported yourself back to the 1990's, this isn't MS-DOS. It's a Windows command prompt.

Comment: Please insert your code correctly; when you run it as stated, there is no output to the `.ftp` file , and the error message `/ was unexpected at this time.`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(echo in10xml
    echo xml_in10
    for /f %i in (verifica.txt) echo put %i /content/UPLOAD/%~nxi
    echo bye)> upload_files_xml.ftp
```